# Email : Target Language

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template

I am trying to set the target language to default to Unicode UFT-8 as opposed to ASCII when creating emails.
[image]

Looked through documentation, but it doesn't seem to mention this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the default on this dropdown. The newer Content Builder UI was created more recently and by a team that realised from the outset that some folks out their send emails in languages other than English and that ASCII doesn't even cover the entirety English language. You'll note that when you create new emails in Content Builder, the default is UTF-8.